# how to connect to sql server on Amazon EC2 from local machine

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying  to connect to db on EC2 from my local machine, I am not able to do and have tried many steps such as inserting data through my application to my Ec2 database using the connection string but failed came up with a database fail connection error, i also tried to deploy my application to my ec2 which seemed to have worked however i can see the folders but the files are missing. i tried to look for answer on the internet however there are too many different ideas.

Can anyone provides guidance or help would appreciate it. thanks in advance

Comment: Connecting from what? Your application? SSMS? PuTTY? Telnet? Help us out here.

Comment: @JacobH my SSMS and application

Comment: What's the error? You followed the instructions here (like using a comma for the port number) and you are using a valid sql login/pass? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

Comment: What did you provide as server name? What authentication method?

Comment: You need to analyse it methodically rather than just trying random stuff. Start with SSMS. If you haven't yet followed the guide in the prior comment, do it, then indicate where it failed and _what the error message is_

Comment: @JacobH i think you are referring to the Amazon RDS.  what i do have is the Amazon Ec2 instance where i have installed SSMS  and create a database but unable to connect this database to my application

Comment: You might want to open tcp port for allowing inbound and outbound connections. Enable Tcp connection on Sal server instance. The port number is 1433 if I am not wrong. What error you get when you try to connect using SSMS?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am getting the "netwwork-related or instance-specific error, and yeah that was my next port on trying to open this port

Comment: Try opening the port and it should work.